# GROUP BY in datatable select using c#

Tags: c#, sql, group-by

I have a dataTable which has rows as shown in below image,[image]

I would like to write groupby statement with select on that datatable for getting output as below,

[image]

Comment: And what is the question? Furthermore: did you try ANYTHING to achieve what you want?

Comment: I personally would like a lot of things... but typically nobody will give them to me, especially when I have done no work to get those things.

Comment: Based on your title "GROUP BY in datatable select using c#", so you want to group the data in C# and not using sql. Any reason **why**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `LINQ` in `C#`

```
var result = from tab in dt.AsEnumerable()
             group tab by tab["ApplicationNmae"]
                 into groupDt
                 select new
                 {
                     ApplicationNmae = groupDt.Key,
                     Sum = groupDt.Sum((r) => decimal.Parse(r["Count"].ToString()))
                 };

DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1 = dt.Clone();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    DataRow newRow = dt1.NewRow();
    newRow["ApplicationNmae"] = item.ApplicationNmae;
    newRow["Count"] = item.Sum;
    dt1.Rows.Add(newRow);
}

Grid.DataSource = dt1;
```

Ref: [Group by in DataTable Column sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736831/group-by-in-datatable-column-sum)

Comment: I need to bind this resultSet to gridView further How do I do that

Comment: Could you please suggest me some important links for learning linq queries from basic things.

Comment: could you please explain the query and which count exactly its giving ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select ApplicationName, count(*) from DataTableName
group by ApplicationName
```

where `DataTableName` should be replaced by the actual name of your table in the database, and `ApplicationName` should be replaced by the name of the column in that table that contains applicatin name

Answer (score 0):

Simply this...

```
SELECT ApplicationName, COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM THETABLENAME
GROUP BY ApplicationName
```

or with ordering and filtering (where there is a duplication and order by the count)...

```
SELECT ApplicationName, COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM THETABLENAME
GROUP BY ApplicationName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```