# DataTable.Select() to display summation of records in datatable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In my C# project in a DataTable, I need to sum a few columns and display the aggregated record and I am unable to create filter query for that.

Records like:

```
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|  
| A  | X  | 10 | 10 |  
| A  | X  | 10 | 20 |  
| A  | Y  | 12 | 12 |  
| A  | Y  | 10 | 10 |
```

Result will be:

```
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|  
| A  | X  | 20 | 30 |  
| A  | Y  | 22 | 22 |
```

I have to use `DataTable.Select("filter condition")`.

Comment: `DataTable.GroupBy(item => new {item.Col1, item.Col2}).Select(chunk => new {Col1 = chunk.Key.Col1, Col2 = chunk.Key.Col2, Col3 = chunk.Sum(item => item.Col3), Col4 = chunk.Sum(item => item.Col4)})`

Comment: Why you tag LINQ when you have to use [`DataTable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) which is not LINQ?

Comment: Something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7736897/7948962) ? Uses `Compute` instead of `Select` but it's a DT and no LINQ.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I can use LinQ thing is being a legacy system i have to optimize this application with minimal changes. Apologies if my sentence misinterpret my intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = (from DataRow s in yourDataTable.Select("filter conditions").AsEnumerable()
              group s by new {g1 = s.Field<string>("Col1"), g2 = s.Field<string>("Col2") } into g
              select new
              {
                  Col1 = g.Key.g1,
                  Col2 = g.Key.g2,
                  Col3 = g.sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Col3")),
                  Col4 = g.sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Col4")),
               }).ToList();
```

And if you want result as DataTable type, you can convert list to DataTable Like below:

```
var resultAsDataTable = ConvertListToDataTable(result);

public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }
    object[] values = new object[props.Count];
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
        }
        table.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: _"I have to use DataTable.Select("filter condition")"_ That sounds as if he cant use LINQ

Comment: DataTable can use LINQ, you must cast your datatable with `AsEnumerable()` and after that you can make linq query on IEnumerable object.

Comment: Yes, but OP stated that he must use `DataTable.Select` which is strange because he also tagged LINQ. It seems like someone told him to avoid LINQ maybe because they can't use it.

Comment: @HasanGholamali: Thanks for your answer . Can you please add as how can i append other columns in this result and change the column names as per application's specification. Like this table has following columns: Parent Code(Col1 in my question), Child Code(Col2 in my question), Buy Qty (Col3), Buy Price (Col4) and 6 more columns like -Sell Qty, Sell Price, Reason, Date, Update Time, Message.

Comment: @AshishJaiswal just replace the names and in select you can use all enumerable methods like `.ToList()` and `.FirstOrDefault()`
I don't know what you want exactly, if you have problem edit question with your column name and result you want.

Comment: @HasanGholamali: I got the desired result. Thank you so much for help. Just one thing since i needed the result in datatable format so when i tried to implement  `result.CopyToDataTable();` its giving error.

Comment: I edited the answer and add convert list to datatable.